# showing a spinner when using ng-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input field which fetches location based on user search. For this I am using the ng-automplete directive and is working well. Now am planning to add loading bar when the user searches. So once they start typing, a loading bar will be shown until a list is returned from ng-autocomplete. So to do that I added a loading image to my input field like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 form-group fake-input">
   <input type="text" ng-autocomplete ng-model="searchLocation" class="form-control input-lg"  options="locationFilter">
   <span ng-show="searchStatus()">  
     <img src="<%= asset_path ('search-spinner.gif') %>" width=25 /> 
   </span>
 </div>
```

I also added an ng-show to show and hide the image based on the search result. But am unable to figure out where to actually put the searchStatus scope in the ng-autocomplete..Could someone tell me where to set that. if its a controller I can use like $scope.searchStatus = true or so. But as this is a directive am confused on how to do that..

here is the directive code

```
'use strict';

/**
 * A directive for adding google places autocomplete to a text box
 * google places autocomplete info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 * <input type="text"  ng-autocomplete ng-model="autocomplete" options="options" details="details/>
 *
 * + ng-model - autocomplete textbox value
 *
 * + details - more detailed autocomplete result, includes address parts, latlng, etc. (Optional)
 *
 * + options - configuration for the autocomplete (Optional)
 *
 *       + types: type,        String, values can be 'geocode', 'establishment', '(regions)', or '(cities)'
 *       + bounds: bounds,     Google maps LatLngBounds Object, biases results to bounds, but may return results outside these bounds
 *       + country: country    String, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code. examples; 'ca', 'us', 'gb'
 *       + watchEnter:         Boolean, true; on Enter select top autocomplete result. false(default); enter ends autocomplete
 *
 * example:
 *
 *    options = {
 *        types: '(cities)',
 *        country: 'ca'
 *    }
 **/

angular.module( "ngAutocomplete", [])
    .directive('ngAutocomplete', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                options: '=?',
                details: '=?'
            },

            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

                //options for autocomplete
                var opts
                var watchEnter = false
                //convert options provided to opts
                var initOpts = function() {

                    opts = {}
                    if (scope.options) {

                        if (scope.options.watchEnter !== true) {
                            watchEnter = false
                        } else {
                            watchEnter = true
                        }

                        if (scope.options.types) {
                            opts.types = []
                            opts.types.push(scope.options.types)
                            scope.gPlace.setTypes(opts.types)
                        } else {
                            scope.gPlace.setTypes([])
                        }

                        if (scope.options.bounds) {
                            opts.bounds = scope.options.bounds
                            scope.gPlace.setBounds(opts.bounds)
                        } else {
                            scope.gPlace.setBounds(null)
                        }

                        if (scope.options.country) {
                            opts.componentRestrictions = {
                                country: scope.options.country
                            }
                            scope.gPlace.setComponentRestrictions(opts.componentRestrictions)
                        } else {
                            scope.gPlace.setComponentRestrictions(null)
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (scope.gPlace == undefined) {
                    scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], {});
                }
                google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
                    var result = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
                    if (result !== undefined) {
                        if (result.address_components !== undefined) {

                            scope.$apply(function() {

                                scope.details = result;

                                controller.$setViewValue(element.val());
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            if (watchEnter) {
                                getPlace(result)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })

                //function to get retrieve the autocompletes first result using the AutocompleteService
                var getPlace = function(result) {
                    var autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
                    if (result.name.length > 0){
                        autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(
                            {
                                input: result.name,
                                offset: result.name.length
                            },
                            function listentoresult(list, status) {
                                if(list == null || list.length == 0) {

                                    scope.$apply(function() {
                                        scope.details = null;
                                    });

                                } else {
                                    var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(element[0]);
                                    placesService.getDetails(
                                        {'reference': list[0].reference},
                                        function detailsresult(detailsResult, placesServiceStatus) {

                                            if (placesServiceStatus == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                                scope.$apply(function() {

                                                    controller.$setViewValue(detailsResult.formatted_address);
                                                    element.val(detailsResult.formatted_address);

                                                    scope.details = detailsResult;

                                                    //on focusout the value reverts, need to set it again.
                                                    var watchFocusOut = element.on('focusout', function(event) {
                                                        element.val(detailsResult.formatted_address);
                                                        element.unbind('focusout')
                                                    })

                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    );
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }

                controller.$render = function () {
                    var location = controller.$viewValue;
                    element.val(location);
                };

                //watch options provided to directive
                scope.watchOptions = function () {
                    return scope.options
                };
                scope.$watch(scope.watchOptions, function () {
                    initOpts()
                }, true);

            }
        };
    });
```

In my app.js the only thing I use for this directive is this

```
$scope.locationFilter = {
    country: 'ca',
    types: '(cities)'
};
$scope.details2 = '';
```